# Can't connect to oracle database from php

Tags: php, oracle, database-connection

I'm having problem connecting to mydatabase from php. I can connect with no problems from my C# code like that:

```
    private void test()  
    {
        string connect = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));Uid=user;Pwd=pass";
        string queryString = "DELETE FROM myTabel";

        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connect))
        {
            try
            {
                OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString, connection);
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
                log.Debug("Lokalni podatki pobrisani!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ne dela" + e.ToString());
                deluje = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

and that realy delete all data because i check with oracle SQL Developer with which i have no problem connecting to. 
But when i try to run that code:

```
          $tnsname = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))';
    }

    $db['default']['hostname'] = $tnsname;
     $db['default']['username'] = "esz";
      $db['default']['password'] = "test";
      $db['default']['database'] = "esz";
     $db['default']['dbdriver'] = "oci8";
     $db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
      $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
     $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
     $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
     $db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
     $db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
     $db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci"; 

  echo 'Trying to connect to database: ' .$db['default']['database'];
  $dbh=mysql_connect( $db['default['hostname'],$db['default'['username'],$db['default']['password'])
   or die('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
```

I get those errors:

```
 mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. 
 mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is kn (trying to connect via tcp://(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = XE))):3306)
 php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

In line where i try to excecute mysql_connect().

Thank u all for any help!

Comment: did you install oracle client? and you are using mysql specific connection to interact with oracle database. Why are you using `mysql_connect` if the database is Oracle?

Comment: `$dbh=mysql_connect( $db['default['hostname'],$db['default']['username'],$db['default']['password'])` seems like broken line.

Comment: i replaced mysql_connecto to oci_connnect and i get here Message: oci_connect() [function.oci-connect]: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: and yes i have oracle client installed.

Comment: ok now i get to that problem:  Message: oci_connect() [function.oci-connect]: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: Is your PHP code running on the same machine as the C# example? Did you perchance run the C# code on the same machine as the database? Is there a firewall on the machine hosting the database?

Comment: it's all on the same machine, right now i figure out that my database is starting and stoping unexcpectactly :S Now i cant start it anymore so nothing works, and i have no idea what i did.

Answer (score 0):

Use oci_connect as follows:

```
$user = ...;
$password = ...;
$url = '//dbserver:1521/dbname';
$connection = oci_connect ($user, $password, $url);
...
$query = '...';
$stid = oci_parse ($connection, $query);
oci_execute ($stid);
oci_fetch ($stid);
```

and the like

Comment: if i do so i get that error     Message: oci_connect() [function.oci-connect]: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener